Modify Ubuntu Text Editor Setting to close the file when exit
When I open Text Editor, it will open the last file. I wonder if I can modify the setting to disable it. If so, how can I do.
My System is Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS Desktop. I don't know which version the text-editor is. But I just update it yesterday.

See the Saved Session section of this article

This wouldn't be so bad if they kept the tabs up so we could actually close the final file and not have it restored the next time. The menu doesn't even have a close file entry, nor any indication that Ctrl+W exists. A new file is loaded on start, so you have to know how to close a file before you ever even see the start screen to learn how to close a file (it does show Ctrl+W). This is horrible! First day of fresh install and I am already replacing this. They don't even have an option to disable the recent items?

The only recourse is to disable "Restore Session" or train yourself to use Ctrl+W before closing the app.
To disable "Restore Session", open settings (Ctrl+,) and scroll all the way down to find it.

Thank you very much.
